# How can I change the background color of column's cells in highcharts gatt?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the background color of a cell's in yAxis columns in highcharts? and how can I set a background color for each row of the chart?

for example, in this case, I want to change the background color of the middle cell in the second row. and also change the background color of the third row.
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gvaartjes/4g7ekw65/)

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    grid: {      
      borderColor: '#3a5d96',      
      columns: [{
        title: {
          text: 'Tasks',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        }
      }, {
        title: {
          text: 'Assignee',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        },
        labels: {
          format: '{point.assignee}'
        }
      }, {
        title: {
          text: 'Duration',
          rotation: 45,
          y: -15,
          x: -15
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            var point = this.point,
              days = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
              number = (point.end - point.start) / days;
            return Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am afraid that with the current implementation it is impossible because the grid lines are rendered as the SVG Paths and the space between them is not defined anywhere. The only idea which came to my mind is to color labels, but this solution is far away from perfect: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lt471agy/

Comment: Another idea which came to my mind is to use the SVGRenderer tool to render the rect which will be in the background: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/13snfg48/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks, the second way is more interesting for me. I've done it in this way.